# Realm: Can a local realm exist while using a server synced realm?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a server synced realm that is working fine. I would like to add an aditional local realm to store some items locally only:

```
  this.userRealm = new Realm({
    path: 'userRealm.realm',
    schema: [cgps_schema.DirectoryFavoritesSchema],
  });
```

This does not appear to work. Perhaps its not intended to?

If I call new Realm() before attempting to conect to my synced realm, it creates the userRealm.realm.management directory and the userRealm.realm.lock file, but not the userRealm.realm file. If I call new Realm() after conecting to my synched realm, it creates all the files and works, but when I reload the app it deletes userRealm.realm and creates a new blank one.

Comment: How do you open the synced realm? Does it have the same local path as the unsynced one?

Comment: I open it with the code posted above that provides an alternate path from the default realm.

Comment: It just started working out of the blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different `path` when you open different realms. Here is some code that opens 1 synced realm and 1 unsynced realm:

```
const Realm = require('realm');

const ItemSchema = {name: 'Item', properties: {id: 'int', name: 'string'}};

const unsynced = new Realm({
    path: 'unsynced.realm',
    schema: [ItemSchema],
})

Realm.Sync.User.register('http://localhost:9080', 'user1', 'pass1', (error, user) => {
    const synced = new Realm({
        path: 'synced.realm',
        schema: [ItemSchema],
        sync: {
            url: 'realm://localhost:9080/~/synced',
            user: user,
        },
    })
    synced.close();
    user.logout();
    unsynced.close();
})
```

Comment: My code now works now, not sure why as I didn't really change anything. But this is the correct way to do it so marking correct.